# jQuery remember original textbox value on multiple focusin events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Difficult to get the explaination right so here's a little [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cw1nkzhe/).

I have a form with multiple `input:text` and one `button:submit`. The submit button gets enabled when any of the form controls has changed. Also textboxes `onchange` gets a new fancy yellow `background-color` with `addClass` to indicate that the value has been changed. The original value is stored on the `focusin` event then compared with the new value `onchange`.

But, my goal is when I change the textbox value and focusin again I would like to have the original old value to not change, so that the background-color can be reseted.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the defaultValue property

```js
var adminWeb = window.adminWeb || {};

adminWeb.dirtyHandling = (function() {
  var createView = function() {
    $("form")
      .each(function() {
        $(this).data("serialized", $(this).serialize());
      }).on("change input", 'input:text', function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("textbox-changed", this.value !== this.defaultValue);

        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        $form.find("input:submit, button:submit")
          .prop("disabled", $form.serialize() === $form.data("serialized"));
      })
      .find("input:submit, button:submit")
      .prop("disabled", true);
  };

  return {
    init: createView
  };

})();

$(function() {
  adminWeb.dirtyHandling.init();
});
```

```css
.textbox-changed {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="Carl" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
  <input type="text" value="Johnson" name="lastname" id="lasttname" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button id="submit-data" disabled="" type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

---

If you want to make your code work, use a data property to store the original value once

```js
var adminWeb = window.adminWeb || {};

adminWeb.dirtyHandling = (function() {
  var createView = function() {
    $("form")
      .each(function() {
        $(this).data("serialized", $(this).serialize());
      }).on("focusin input:text", function(e) {
        var $t = $(e.target);
        var dvalue = $t.data('default-value');
        if (typeof dvalue == 'undefined') {
          $t.data('default-value', $t.val())
        }
      }).on("change input", function(e) {
        var txt = $(e.target);
        if (txt.is("input:text")) {
          txt.addClass("textbox-changed");
          if (txt.val() === txt.data('default-value')) { //oldVal comparison
            //should allways be same
            txt.removeClass("textbox-changed");
          }
        }

        $(this)
          .find("input:submit, button:submit")
          .prop("disabled", $(this).serialize() === $(this).data("serialized"));
      })
      .find("input:submit, button:submit")
      .prop("disabled", true);
  };

  return {
    init: createView
  };

})();

$(function() {
  adminWeb.dirtyHandling.init();
});
```

```css
.textbox-changed {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="Carl" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
  <input type="text" value="Johnson" name="lastname" id="lasttname" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button id="submit-data" disabled="" type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a data- attribute to store the original value and check against that attribute to determine whether or not to set the class.Iterate over each one to see if none of them are changed. Something like...

```
<input data-original="Carl" value='Carl' type='text' />
<input type='submit id='submit' />

var textInputs$ = $('[data-original]');

$('[data-original]').change(function (e) {
    var changed = false;
    $.each(textInputs$, function () {
        var self$ = $(this);
        if (self$.attr('data-original') != self$.val()) {
            self$.addClass('yellow');
            changed = true;
        }
    });

    if (changed) {
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question. Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4yzm2czv/) what you'r trying to achieve?

You need to remove class in `focusin` event.